# Is it legal to embed fonts as images on my website?

Tags: web, fonts, embed

I have Myriad installed on my computer and would like to use it as the banner font for my website. I know that without a webfont licence it would be illegal to do so but my banner is png/jpg file, is this perfectly ok/legal to do?

Comment: Yes, it is. You're using an asset created with a legally owned typeface, and the asset cannot be used to reverse engineer the typeface itself. That said, this is not a programming question, but a legal question, so should probably not have been asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance, I would check the licence for the font you're using. It should be able to inform you of how that font can be used.

Also, what research have you done so far? I did some quick googling and found this page: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/myriad/licensing.html

I'm no legal expert, but this web page should make things clear.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thx for the link. i guess it should be fine according to this point they make: Create and print documents, as well as static images (.jpeg, .tiff, .png), even if the images are used on the web or in a mobile app.